# Druid gatherings?

Tags: magic, medieval

Druids could have massive gatherings once at a time. To talk about things they've noticed, possible world/nature threats, welcome or test new druids, or other things.

I'm looking for ideas and details about this druid gathering thing. Could you post any suggestions? Why would druids meets up? How do they tell each other about where/when to meet? What are they doing when they meet? Do they do it often or rarelly?

I have some ideas but I'm very interested to read your thoughts too and get some inspiration.

Comment: While interesting, this question is far too broad. I recommend you to start studying about real Earth druids and how they used to do things. There are also neopagan groups like [ADF](https://www.adf.org/) where you can get some more info

Answer (score 2):

Digging into the cliche-jar a bit here, but it might serve:

"Where": Stone circles - where those were placed? Why, obviously at places where strong Ley-lines cross!

"When": Well, the solstices are traditional. Plus during any mystically significant occurence they foresee - like solar eclipses, alignments of the planets, and the like. Dates that any good druid could easily calculate on their own.

"Why": To discuss their scryings about future developments in the world, to share knowledge from their research, and instruct each others' apprentices in things that said apprentice's master isn't as knowledgeable about as other druids at the meeting. Plus, a nice meet-n-greet with totally mystical and not just tasty booze. And the talking is about the fate of the world, who are you to call it "gossip"? ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Why would druids meets up? How do they tell each other about where/when to meet?

During astrological events like the summer solstice, every druid with a sundial would know roughly how many days/weeks/months until they need to go to wherever they agreed to meet last time.

> What are they doing when they meet?

Talk, trade, teach, smoke, drink and eat, maybe they had rituals, maybe there was a hierarchy, the Christians stamped out Paganism so it's hard to know for sure.

> Do they do it often or rarely?

Nobody really knows, there's various tribal/shamanistic cultures around the world where groups of men and women go off on their own for secret reasons, maybe you can use them for inspiration?